# PowerShell loop until variable

Tags: powershell, loops

I have a simple piece of code, that I want to loop until it reaches the variable given by the user (i.e. if the user says 3, loop 3 times)

```
$quantidade = Read-Host -Prompt 'NUMERO DE INSTANCIAS'
$loop = 0
while ($loop -ne $quantidade) {
    $Servers = Read-Host -Prompt 'NOME SQL'
    $Version = Read-Host -Prompt 'VERSAO SQL? (2014,2012,...'

    if ($Version -eq "2014") {
        Write-Host "VERSAO 2014"
        $VERSQL = "12"
    } elseif ($Version -eq "2008") {
        Write-Host "VERSAO 2008"
        $VERSQL = "10"
    } elseif ($Version -eq "2012") {
        Write-Host "VERSAO 2012"
        $VERSQL = "11"
    } elseif ($Version -eq "2016") {
        Write-Host "VERSAO 2016"
        $VERSQL = "13"
    } elseif ($Version -eq "2017") {
        Write-Host "VERSAO 2017"
        $VERSQL = "14"
    } else {
        Write-Host "ERRO"
        break
    }

    Write-Host "You input server '$Servers' and '$Version'"

    $SQL = -join("%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL", $VERSQL, ".", $Servers, "\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe")

    Write-Host $SQL
    $loop = $lopp + 1
    Write-Host $loop
}
```

I know whats wrong, the sum is being done inside the loop, making it always 0+1 =1. Whats the better way to go around this?

Comment: Use 'for' statement https://ss64.com/ps/for.html
BTW you have a typo here `$loop=$lopp+1`

Comment: Also take a look at `switch` to replace you chain of `if` & `else`. https://ss64.com/ps/switch.html

Comment: But can i store the decision the user took? I was using it but had no way to store the "decision"

Comment: Your problem is caused by a typo in your calculation (`$loop = $lopp + 1`), not by the calculation being inside the loop. That should've been `$loop = $loop + 1`, or `$loop += 1`, or just `$loop++`. But you also need to convert the user input to an integer (`[int]$quantidade = Read-Host ...`), otherwise the comparison won't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution (that i managed to make work so far with the help of you guys, although i would LOVE to get the switch to work with it) is this one

```
$Quantidade = Read-Host -Prompt 'NUMERO DE INSTANCIAS'

for ($i=1;$i -le $quantidade;$i++) {

$Servers = Read-Host -Prompt 'NOME SQL'
$Version = Read-Host -Prompt 'VERSAO SQL? (2014,2012,...'

if($Version -eq "2014"){
Write-Host "VERSAO 2014"
$VERSQL="12"
}
elseif($Version -eq"2008"){
Write-Host "VERSAO 2008"
$VERSQL="10"
}
elseif($Version -eq"2012")
{Write-Host "VERSAO 2012"
$VERSQL="11"
}
elseif($Version -eq"2016"){
Write-Host "VERSAO 2016"
$VERSQL="13"
}
elseif($Version -eq"2017")
{Write-Host "VERSAO 2017"
$VERSQL="14"
}
else{
Write-Host "ERRO"
break
}
```